# Show that $\dfrac{b}{a} = -(A+B+C)$ and $\dfrac{c}{a} = (AB+AC + BC)$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let´s assume we have the polynomial: $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

This polynomial has three zero points: $A$, $B$ and $C$.

How can I show that $$\dfrac{b}{a} = -(A+B+C)$$

and

$$\dfrac{c}{a} = (AB + AC + BC)$$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, I tried like this: `ax^3+bx^2+cx+d` = `(x-A)(x-B)(x-C)` = `x^3 - Cx^2 - Bx^2 + BCx - Ax^2 + ABx - ABC`

Comment: But then I have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

HINT: note that if $A,B,C$ are the zero points of $$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$ then you can write
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=a(x-A)(x-B)(x-C)$$
so $b=-a(A+B+C)$ etc.

Comment: Yes, and `a(x - A)(x - B)(x - C)` = `ax^3 - aCx^2 - aBx^2 + aBCx - a^2x^2 + a^2Cx + a^2Bx - a^2BC`